# Dividing a dataframe column and then rounding

Tags: python, pandas

I have been manipulating some data frames, but unfortunately I have two percentage columns, one in the format '61.72' and the other '0.62'.

I want to just divide the column with the percentages in the '61.72' format by 100 then round it to 2.dp so it is consistent with the data frame.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

My data frame has two columns, one called 'A' and the other 'B', I want to format 'B'.

Comment: It's generally good practice not to round numbers that you're still going to do math on later. You lose nothing by having a bit of extra precision, and it's easy to print a rounded version of the numbers while still keeping the extra precision behind the scenes.

Comment: That is a good point. I was going to do cluster analysis, but wanted to put the figures to 2dp in a table for the report for easy viewing, but you are right, I can do that at the end. Much appreciated

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[61.75, 10.25], 'B':[0.62, 0.45]})
print (df)
       A     B
0  61.75  0.62
1  10.25  0.45

df['A'] = df['A'].div(100).round(2)
#same as
#df['A'] = (df['A'] / 100).round(2)
print (df)
      A     B
0  0.62  0.62
1  0.10  0.45
```

Comment: You're blazing fast sir haha

Comment: wow, that is quick, and much simpler than what I was trying to do (with not much success!)..... thank you!

Comment: Just to confirm its all working. Thank you :).... ill mark your answer as correct as soon as I am allowed

Answer (score 5):

This question have already got answered but here is another solution which is significantly **faster** and **standard** one.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[10, 3.50], 'y':[30.1, 50.8]})
print (df)
>>      x     y
    0  10.0  30.1
    1   3.5  50.8

df = df.loc[:].div(100).round(2)
print (df)
>>        x       y
   0    0.10    0.30
   1    0.03    0.50
```

why prefer this solution??

well, this warning is enough answer - "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame if you use df['A'] so, Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead."

Moreover, check this for more understanding https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: this is not the same though. this divides EVERY column by a constant, not - as in the previous example - only ONE. i'm looking for the latter.