# Division in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to divide my data frame with one of its columns:

Here is my data frame:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | 30 |
| 3 | 15 | 33 |

Now, I want to divide columns "b" and "c" by column "a", my desired output be like:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 | 15 |
| 3 | 5 | 11 |

```
df/df['a']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Panda Python - dividing a column by 100 (then rounding by 2.dp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675014/panda-python-dividing-a-column-by-100-then-rounding-by-2-dp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df[['B','C']] = df[['B','C']].div(df['A'], axis=0)
print (df)
   A     B     C
0  1  10.0  10.0
1  2  10.0  15.0
2  3   5.0  11.0
```

If need divide all columns without `A`:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['A'])
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['A'], axis=0)
```

Comment: one more doubt if we have more than 1k columns then?

Comment: @AmitKumar - Sure, give me a sec.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
d = {
    'A': [1,2,3],
    'B': [10,20,15],
    'C': [10,30,33]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['B'] = df['B']/df['A']
df['C'] = df['C']/df['A']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A     B     C
0  1  10.0  10.0
1  2  10.0  15.0
2  3   5.0  11.0
```